# Execute Linux Command and Get PID

Tags: python, linux

Normally I use:

```
os.popen("du folder >> 1.txt ").read()
```

It was working fine.
But when I wanted to grab the subprocess id, it returns the empty value.

```
os.popen("du folder >> 1.txt &").read() # Notice the & symbol
```

Does anyone know why and how to get the PID?

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to use the `subprocess` module.

```
# Can't use shell=True if you want the pid of `du`, not the
# shell, so we have to do the redirection to file ourselves
proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/du folder", stdout=file("1.txt", "ab"))
print "PID:", proc.pid
print "Return code:", proc.wait()
```

Comment: I tried your code under python 2.7, it always popup some error:


File "/home/ben/qiime_software/python-2.7.3-release/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Your `du` command may be somewhere else. Try `which du` to find out where.

Answer (score 0):

`&` puts the process in to background and the job number != pid. To get a pid of your process.

I suggest using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) - a `Popen` instance has attribute `pid` that you can directly access.