# How to find the name of a process spawned by Python?

Tags: python, linux, process

I am on Linux and wish to find the process spawned by a Python command.

Example: `shutil.copyfile`.

How do I do so?

Generally I have just read the processes from the terminal with `ps` however this command completes nearly instantaneously so I cannot do that for this without some lucky timing.

htop doesn't show the info, strace seems to show a lot of info but I can't seem to get the process in it.

Comment: You mean: this (python) command completes nearly instantaneously so you can't see it clearly with ps?

Comment: @Johnny yeah, taht is what I meant. usually I just do it manually with ps ax etc but now I would like to know how to get the name of the process in python code.

Comment: try **strace**, "it intercepts and records the system calls which are called by a process and the signals which are received by a process."

I recommend reading man before to custom output to your needs.

Comment: You could use [**`os.nice`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.nice) to give your process a low priority to make it take longer

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152067/execute-linux-command-and-get-pid

Answer (score 0):

Would running a filter in htop be quick enough?

Run htop, Press F5 to enter tree mode, then F4 to filter, and type in python... it should show all the python processes as they open/close